# Is it possible to have a textbox and then load the file into the input to be uploaded?

Tags: jquery, html

We are trying to optimize a file upload admin screen. Most of the images are already on the web so what I'd like to do is just provide a text box where a user can input the URL to the image and then we grab the image via javascript.

The user could then click submit and the normal workflow would happen. Could the html5 File object do this or could this just be done in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying some like this

```
            <input type="text" id="URL">
            <button onclick="loadImg()">submit</button>
            <img src="" id="load"/>


            function loadImg(){
             var url = $("#URL").val()
             $('#load').attr('src',url)
            }
```

codepen URL -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqopjK

Comment: nice, yeah - now how would I assign it to a `input type="file"` or is that possible? Sorry, I mostly do backend dev.

Comment: @timpone No, it is not possible to assign a file to `input type="file"` element; see [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) at _"A read-only value indicating the number of files in the list."_